# 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable when using latent dirichlet allocation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lda

I am trying to apply the latent dirichlet allocation algorithm to a .csv file retrieved from twitter data.

Currently I run across the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...\src\project.py", line 262, in topic-modelling-lda
    for i in top_topic_words:
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

The libraries I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re, random
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
```

This is my code for that function

```
def topic-modelling-lda(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('sample_dataset.csv')

        vect = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.6, min_df=4, stop_words='english')
        matrix = vect .fit_transform(df)

        LDA = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=5, random_state=50)
        LDA.fit(matrix)

        first_topic = LDA.components_[0]
        top_topic_words = first_topic.argsort()[-10]
        for i in top_topic_words:
            print(count_vect.get_feature_names()[i])
```

The line 262 is the `for i in top_topic_words:`.

I am unsure how I am to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to select the top 10 words and you are using a wrong syntax. You are only selecting the word ranked 10 which is not iterable. Change line 261 to this to select the top 10 instead of only selecting the 10th:

```
top_topic_words = first_topic.argsort()[-10:]
```